# Apollo Graphql Import Issue with cacheControl directive

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, apollo-server, express-graphql

I am using `"graphql-import": "^0.7.1"`

I tried to add `@cacheControl` directive to my graphql schema

```
type Post @cacheControl(maxAge: 240) {
  id: Int!
  title: String
  author: Author
  votes: Int @cacheControl(maxAge: 30)
  readByCurrentUser: Boolean! @cacheControl(scope: PRIVATE)
}
```

then it was giving this error -

```
Error: Directive cacheControl: Couldn't find type cacheControl in any of the schemas.
```

So after taking hints from link -

https://github.com/prisma/graphql-import/issues/153

I added below code

```
directive @cacheControl(
  maxAge: Int,
  scope: CacheControlScope
) on OBJECT | FIELD_DEFINITION

enum CacheControlScope {
  PUBLIC
  PRIVATE
}
```

But after that I started getting this error -

```
Error: There can be only one type named "CacheControlScope".

Enum value "CacheControlScope.PUBLIC" can only be defined once.

Enum value "CacheControlScope.PRIVATE" can only be defined once.
```

I am not able to figure out how to fix this issue.

Comment: Can you try to put the cacheDirective on a directives.graphql and then import it (
# import cacheControl from 'directives.graphql' ) and see if it works ?

Comment: @jgoday I tried that as well but still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faced this problem as well and the directive not being found has to due with schema stitching. I used the same work around you used by placing the directive and enum definition in the schema itself. When I encounter that error I had to upgrade to at least 2.6.6 because that is where they added a fix for the dupe error you are getting ref: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/pull/2762

Answer (score 2):

Where do you declare those enum and directive?
I kept getting these errors just because I've put them into a typedef file that was being referenced more than once.
Then I've just moved this code to my main schema file

```
const CacheControl = gql`
    enum CacheControlScope {
        PUBLIC
        PRIVATE
    }

    directive @cacheControl (
        maxAge: Int
        scope: CacheControlScope
    ) on FIELD_DEFINITION | OBJECT | INTERFACE
`
...

const typeDefs = [
    CacheControl,
    ...
]

const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    ...
})
```

and the problem was gone.

Answer (score 2):

Static hints are giving me the same errors, so I have tried with dynamic ones inside resolvers and it works.

Regarding to [Apollo Docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/caching/):

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    post: (_, { id }, _, info) => {
      info.cacheControl.setCacheHint({ maxAge: 60, scope: 'PRIVATE' });
      return find(posts, { id });
    }
  }
}
```

[image: cache control]